# JScrollPane: Autoscroll in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jscrollpane

I know there are a lot of questions similar to this one, but unfortunately they are all about auto scrolling a `scrollBar` inside of a TextArea.

I use a `JScrollPane` to simulate a `JList`: I add small `JPanels` to a `JScrollPane` with `GridLayout`, and they stack verically.

I want the scroll bar to follow the last added element (down), but I can't get it to work.

I tried to adapt some of the answers for the `Text`, such as:

```
.autoScrolls(true);
```

or

```
JScrollBar vertical = scollPan.getVerticalScrollBar();
vertical.setValue( vertical.getMaximum() );
```

and even one on changing the updatePolicy, but nothing works for a JScrollPane that isn't bound to a text area, I can only scroll the bar manually.

```
vertical.setValue( vertical.getMaximum() );
```

did do something, it scrolls the bar down, but just about 2/3 of the way, and only because I added `.revalidate()` on the scrollPane after calling it.

Any idea?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Why not use a `JList` (with a suitable rendering component)?

Comment: I cannot use the JList because the items in the list come from a complicated API and the JList doesn't support them properly, they have their own layout, custom graphics, functionalities, overlay, mouse and drag detection, multiple inner panes, settings, they change according to other events etc. This is part of the reason why I'm having trouble building a MCVE, I'm trying to. I was hoping for a quick obvious solution I was missing due to lack of knowledge..

Comment: `This is part of the reason why I'm having trouble building a MCVE,` - all the stuff you talk about is completely irrelevant when creating an `MCVE`. All that is relevant is adding a component to a panel. The functionality of the panel has nothing to do with scrolling.

Comment: I see, I'm sorry, I tought that the functionality of the items in the list could have something to do with this. Problem solved now anyway, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After add components to the panel you need to do `revalidate()` and `repaint()` to make sure the layout manager is invoked.

```
JScrollBar vertical = scollPan.getVerticalScrollBar();
vertical.setValue( vertical.getMaximum() );
```

Then wrap the above code in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to make sure the code is added to the end of the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` so it is executed after all the layout code.

Comment: Thanks, invokeLater() did the trick. I was apprently setting the new bar position before the layoutmanager had finished.